# Adding { timestamps: true } in @Schema() in Nest.js mongoose model, the record is removed after some time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have found a strange thing, when I added { timestamps: true } to my user model, the records are deleted automatically after some time say 1 min. I have not experience this before, and I am using timeStamps in my other model which works fine.

Comment: Can you provide a code of your model? This could happen for any reason. Perhaps you're having an old TTL index.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a Time To Live index in your collection, so by adding that timestamp field MongoDB automatically deletes the document when the timestamp matches the TTL.

You can view and delete this index easily if you needed to from MongoDB Compass going into indexes:
[image]